# Delete first column in r

Tags: r

how can I delete the first column in r?

I want delete that first column in the picture. I have tried something like that, but here is always the first column visible:

```
y <-tbl.SP500Monthly[1:2]
```

How can I delete the first column?

[image]

It should look like that picture

[image]

```
library(tidyverse) # for overall grammar
library(lubridate) # to parse dates
library(tidyquant) # to download data from yahoo finance
library(glue)      # to automatically construct figure captions
library(scales)    # for nicer axis labels 
library(readxl)    # to read Shiller's data 
library(rio)

tbl.SP500Recent <-  tq_get("^SP500TR", get = "stock.prices",
                           from = "1988-01-04", to = "2022-05-31") %>%
  transmute(Date = date, TotalReturnIndex = close) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Month = ceiling_date(Date, "month")-1) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Month, TotalReturnIndex)
  
  

 

         
  tbl.SP500Index <- tq_get("^GSPC", get = "stock.prices",
                         from = "1871-02-28", to = "2021-12-31") %>%
  transmute(Date = date, Index = close) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Month = ceiling_date(Date, "month") - 1) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Month, Index)
  
  
  tbl.SP500Monthly <- tbl.SP500Recent%>%
  bind_rows(tbl.SP500Historical %>%
              filter(Month < min(tbl.SP500Recent$Month))  %>%
              select(Month, TotalReturnIndex)) %>%
  full_join(tbl.SP500Index %>% 
              select(Month, Index), by = "Month") %>%
  filter(Month >= "1871-02-28")  %>%
  arrange(Month)
tbl.SP500Monthly

fig.Historical <- tbl.SP500Monthly %>%
  select(Month, Index, `Total Return` = TotalReturnIndex) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Month, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  arrange(Month) %>%
  mutate(Value = Value / Value[1] * 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Value, color = Type)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma) +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0), date_breaks = "10 years", date_labels = "%Y") + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
       title = "S&P 500 Index and Total Return Index Since 1871",
       subtitle = glue("Both Indexes are Normalized to 100 at {min(tbl.SP500Monthly$Month)}"))
fig.Historical
y <-tbl.SP500Monthly[1:2]
export(tbl.SP500Monthly, "mxfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: Those are the row names, that cannot be deleted.

Comment: Without test data, it's impossible to be sure, but it looks to me like those are row names, not a column. So `rownames(<yourdataframe>) <- c()` or convert to a tibble might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you'd like to do?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)

tbl.SP500Recent <-  tq_get("^SP500TR", get = "stock.prices",
                           from = "1988-01-04", to = "2022-05-31") %>%
  transmute(Date = date, TotalReturnIndex = close) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Month = ceiling_date(Date, "month")-1) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  filter(Date == max(Date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Month, TotalReturnIndex) %>%
  column_to_rownames("Month")

head(tbl.SP500Recent)
#>            TotalReturnIndex
#> 1988-01-31           257.47
#> 1988-02-29           269.48
#> 1988-03-31           261.15
#> 1988-04-30           264.04
#> 1988-05-31           266.32
#> 1988-06-30           278.54
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to have. I have used your code with my data: tbl.SP500Monthly > column_to_rownames("month"). But then I get this error: Error in column_to_rownames("month") : is.data.frame(.data) is not TRUE

Comment: Updated above to use your data.